# How to remove element with no attributes and child element?

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of elements and I want to remove div elements with no attributes and child element.

Sample code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="xx-1"></div>
  <div id="yy-1"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div><h1>Hello World!</h1></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

How can i remove `<div></div>` inside the wrapper class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the conditions for removal are:

1. DIV tags
2. which have no attributes
3. and have no child elements

Then you'll probably want a filter:

```
$(".wrapper div").filter(function() {
    return this.attributes.length == 0
        && this.childNodes.length == 0;
}).remove();
```

The `div:empty` selector in jQuery will remove all DIV tags with no child nodes, including DIV tags that have attributes and no child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter.

```
$(".wapper div").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == "";
}).remove();
```

This will remove all empty div.

Answer (score 0):

after some investigating and trying, I have got it:

```
$('div:not([class]):not([id]):not(:has(*))').remove();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/1ydsnph3/)

**edit:** ok, that's still not the solution since it's just checking for the `class` and `id` attributes.